# GoogleDrive REST API Authentication without intervention

Tags: google-drive-api

What i need to do is to authenticate myself into the GoolgeDrive API (I use it in python) to access my drive to do some automatique task.

I would like that my script run alone every hour without any intervention. So what i need is a way to create a credentials object with my login and password.

Is it possible without any redirection and so on?

Comment: Try to ask a better question, if you want your question answered. Take a look at this [How-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to achieve this with user id and password. The way Google Drive implements this is using a refresh token. That means that you authenticate your app one time interactively. This enables you app for one hour. If the refresh token mechanism is properly configured, the app will renew the token every time it needs it subsequently.

Basically the following steps need to be taken

- Visit console.developers.google.com
- Register a project and obtain Oauth Client IDs
- Select as type web server and enter "http://localhost:8080/" as authorized redirect URL
- Download the client_secrets.json and store it in the root of your python app
- Create a file called "settings.yaml" at the same place with the following content

  `client_config_backend: settings`
  `client_config:`   
  `client_id: YOUR_CLIENT_ID_GOES_HERE`
  `client_secret: YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_GOES_HERE`

  `save_credentials: True`
  `save_credentials_backend: file`
  `save_credentials_file: credentials.son`

  `get_refresh_token: True`

  `oauth_scope:`
  `- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
  `- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install`
- In your python code you need to do proper authentication and credential saving:

  ```
  gauth = GoogleAuth()
  gauth.settings["get_refresh_token"]=True
  gauth.settings["approval_prompt"]="force"
  if exists(self.credsFile):
      gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(self.credsFile)
  if gauth.credentials is None:
      # Authenticate if they're not there
      gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
      gauth.SaveCredentialsFile(self.credsFile)
  elif gauth.access_token_expired:
      # Refresh them if expired
      gauth.Refresh()
      gauth.Authorize()
  else:
      # Initialize the saved creds
      gauth.Authorize()
      # Save the current credentials to a file
      gauth.SaveCredentialsFile(self.credsFile)
  self.driveInstance= GoogleDrive(gauth)
  ```
- Make sure that you pass in self.credsFile as a valid filename
- Executing this code should give you a URL at the console. Copy it to a browser, authenticate and give your consent. Google should ask you for two consents, the second is to authenticate for Google Drive - which is actually done by the refresh token.
- The redirect url from the initial credential config in the developer console is called once the consent is given. It calls the temporary web server started by your application. This is how the call back is done. (This implies you have to run browser and your app on the same machine for this step - you may copy over all three files to your server)

From now on your app should run forever without requiring user interaction.

Comment: It'seems to be a good solution. I have not tested it and i won't because by now my project took an other direction and i don't even remember why i needed this. Nevermind it looks a good solution and will probably help someone.